# Handling array value in JS

Tags: php, javascript

I have a problem with my arrays in JavaScript. I can't seem to get the value correctly.

I create my array in PHP like this:

```
$data = Array();        
$get = mysql_query("SELECT x,y,sid FROM table WHERE uid='1'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)){
        $data[$row['x']] = Array();
        $data[$row['x']][$row['y']] = $row['sid'];
        }
$data = json_encode($row)
```

EDIT The json_encode comes out as "false" /EDIT

I then assigned this $data to a JS variable as sdata.

So then i try to get the value in JS but its not working. I get an undefined error.

This is my Javascript:

```
var i = 1;
var j = 5;
    if(sdata["x"] == i && sdata["y"] == j){
    alert(sdata["x"]["y"]["sid"]);
            }
```

Its meant to alert me the value of "sid" but i get:
Undefined

Any ideas where my mistake is?

Comment: you have to use sdata.x, sdata.y and sdata.sid and not sdata[x] etc. Please read my answer below and please let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your json

```
alert(sdata["x"]["y"]["sid"]);
```

should be

```
alert(sdata["sid"]);
```

as the json encoded data you show is only a one dimensional array

**EDIT**

If your json comes out as false, that's a different story:

```
$data = json_encode($row);
```

Should be inside your loop, for good practice, and if you're just encoding the $row why even bother with

```
    $data[$row['x']] = Array();
    $data[$row['x']][$row['y']] = $row['sid'];
```

Otherwise try

```
print_r($row);
```

within your while statement and make sure your expected result is coming through from mysql in the first place.

**EDIT**

If you are trying to get the $data variable in json then use

```
$data = json_encode($data);
```

outside of your loop.

**EDIT**

JSFiddle to return sid for given x and y - I'm sure it can be done in a cleaner way, but it's a start
http://jsfiddle.net/HWByj/

```
var sdata = {"4":{"4":"1"},"7":{"1":"0"}};
var i = 4;
var j = 4;

if(typeof sdata[i] != 'undefined')
{
    if(typeof sdata[i][j] != 'undefined')
    {
        alert(sdata[i][j]); //gives you the value of sid
    }
}
        ​
```

Comment: But there could be many rows of data thats why its in a while loop it just so happens in this situation i had one row of data but there could be numerous

Comment: See my last edit - json_encode doesn't support multi-dimensional arrays

Comment: @ErikKettenburg `json_encode` works just fine with multi-dimensional arrays.  Where did you get that from?

Comment: @Crashspeeder you're completely right - I've removed that comment entirely

Comment: this fixed the array issue - i now have :
{"4":{"4":"1"},"7":{"1":"0"}}

But i need to get the value of "1" for example if x is 4 and y is 4 .. which is where im stuck :) As my JS showned above im lost how to check

Comment: Thanks for reply, looks like i got it right sorta but i get a slight bug...http://www.paste.to/MzU2MjM1  - i can get the width value but not the height value.. var id is set to 1 ( i did alerts to check this)

Comment: @Dave where does the castle object come from? Can you post more source, or add source to jsfiddle?

Comment: From this further up the script: http://www.paste.to/MzU2MjQy
IT has to be set if i can get the image width ... so i dunno why i can only get one entity and not the second.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you only need:

```
alert(sdata["sid"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like your problem is here:

```
$data = json_encode($row)
```

I think you want this:

```
$data = json_encode($data);
```

You're looping through the rows and putting data in $data, but then you're encoding the $row variable. You're also using that $row variable to drop out of the while loop, so $row is probably null when you encode it. That's why it's coming out as false.

Answer (score 1):

If your `json_encode()` is returning `false` then make sure you're getting data back from the query.  Additionally, you're not doing anything with `$data`, you're doing the `json_encode()` on `$row`, which will give you a different structure than I believe you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use sdata.x, sdata.y and sdata.sid since the returned json is not an associative array but it's an object.

Try with this piece of js code:

```
function myobjtool(myobj, i, j) {
        // alert("myobj: " + myobj.x);
        if(myobj.x == i && myobj.y == j) {
                alert(myobj.sid);
        }
}

myobj = {"x":"4","y":"4","sid":"1"}
myobjtool(myobj, 4, 4)
```